# Ошибка при подключении к БД Postgres

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

При подключении к базе данных `postgres` последовательно возникли две проблемы.

Первая - ошибка `QPSQL driver not loaded`. Удалось решить через добавление в папку проекта `qt .dll` файлов.
[image]

Затем появилась проблема с невозможностью подключиться к базе данных.

```
inline bool createConnection(){
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("ed_sim");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("89256328258i");
    db.setPort(5432);
    if(!db.open()){
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Database error", "Connection with BD!");
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Connect", "Great");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[image: База данных]

Строка `qDebug` выводит `"connection to server at \"localhost\" (::1), port 5432 failed: ?????:  ???????????? \"postgres\" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)\nQPSQL: Unable to connect"`.

Фукнция вызывается одновременно с создания окна приложения.

Comment: переменная `QSqlDatabase db` заканчивает своё время жизни после выхода из функции. результат - закрытие подключения.

Comment: Подключение даже не проиcходит, QMessageBox указал бы на это ещё во время работы фукнции. 
Уточните, что вы имели ввиду, если я вас не правильно понял.

Comment: Параметры подключения к серверу отсутствуют. ¿Как оно узнает, куда оно должно подключаться?

Comment: @user7860670 Если имеете ввиду ввиду HostName и порт, то их указание ничего не меняет.

Comment: Ну в впросе-то их нет, хотя должны быть. А еще вы не получаете пояснение к ошибке посредством `QSqlDatabase::lastError()`

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за совет с lastError(). Выводит `"connection to server at \"127.0.0.1\", port 5432 failed: ?????:  ???????????? \"postgres\" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)\nQPSQL: Unable to connect"`

Comment: @GellyHoup что в логах сервера PostgreSQL? Факт попытки подключения зафиксирован? Если да то должна быть причина отказа в подключении. Вам не нужен ip6 поставьте listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0' (postgresql.conf),  вы все равно пытаетесь заходить по ip4 странно в ошибке адрес разрешен в localhost в вашем случае такого не должно происходить.

Comment: @DmitryIvanov попытки подключения имеются.

Comment: @GellyHoup так в чем причина отказа сервера? Как правило этой информации бывет достаточно для решения проблемы.